Where should RcppEigen be in description file

I'm unsure how to only put RcppEigen under the LinkingTo and not the Imports headers. I've gotten conflicting instructions and am very confused what to do. I've been learning how to use Eigen myself, so I'm not sure if I did something wrong in writing the functions. I've seen Do I need to import RccpEigen in the DESCRIPTION file for an R package using it, or is "LinkingTo" enough? and understand it should be only under LinkingTo according to the CRAN manual https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#:~:text=Specifying%20a%20package%20in%20%E2%80%98LinkingTo%E2%80%99%20suffices%20if%20these%20are%20C/C%2B%2B%20headers%20containing%20source%20code
Should my code using RcppEigen be in header files or .cpp files? My understanding was that .h was just for empty definitions of the functions if you need to use it in other cpp files, and .cpp was for the implementation of those functions. Right now I've been using .cpp and #include <RcppEigen.h> and letting Rcpp generate the required RcppExports.cpp files

I've tried testing the package with devtools::check_win_devel() since that's what CRAN does and got the reply:
"Package in Depends/Imports which should probably only be in LinkingTo: ‘RcppEigen’".
So accordingly, I removed RcppEigen from the Imports and left it in the LinkingTo section, but now the package fails the R CMD check --as-cran with:
"Namespace dependency missing from DESCRIPTION Imports/Depends entries: 'RcppEigen'
See section 'The DESCRIPTION file' in the 'Writing R Extensions'
manual."
Is there something wrong with how I'm accessing the Eigen objects?

Search for the RcppEigen CRAN page. Look at the "Reverse linking to" packages for examples. Why do you have a namespace dependency to RcppEigen? Are you importing from it in your NAMESPACE file? You shouldn't do that.

My NAMESPACE file was generated by roxygen2 and automatically includes import(RcppEigen) in it. Should I force roxygen to not edit the NAMESPACE? Could it be because of the // [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]] line in the cpp code?

If you import it in your NAMESPACE, you must declare the import in the DESCRIPTION. I don't know what you did to make roxygen2 add that. It shouldn't.

Thanks to @Roland, I found out that my NAMESPACE had an import(RcppEigen) in it which was coming from a file along the path R\<packagename>-package.R that had this in it:
## usethis namespace: start
#' @import RcppEigen
## usethis namespace: end
NULL

By removing the import line, I was able to just put RcppEigen into LinkingTo
